# Swift - RoaringBitmap - Serialize to base64

Tags: swift, bitmap, base64

I am trying to serialise a bloom filter generated in a roaring bitmap format to a base64 string, so that I can save it in MongoDB. But the function `portableSerialize` is a bit tricky for me.

I am so far just testing how it works and I generate a random bloom filter values that I later try to convert to buffer -> to data -> to base64:

```
func generateBloomFilterData(){
    let bitmap = RoaringBitmap()
    for i in 0..<50 { 
        let random = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if random == 0 {
            bitmap.add(UInt32(i))
        } 
    }  
    let count = (Int(bitmap.count) * MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)
    var buffer = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: count)
    _ = bitmap.portableSerialize(buffer: &buffer)
    let uintBuffer = buffer.map { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
    let bufferData = Data(uintBuffer)
    let base64String = bufferData()
    print("buffer size: \(buffer.count), \(uintBuffer.count), base64: \(bufferData.base64EncodedString())")
    //-> send base64 string to database
}
```

This generates an error:

> malloc: MallocStackLogging: attempting to release an index out of
> bounds

The console shows:

> buffer size: 20, 20, base64: OjAAAAEAAAAAABMAEAAAAAMABQA=

Is there a way how to simply generate a base64 string out of the above generated **RoaringBitmap(https://github.com/RoaringBitmap)** ?

Comment: What is a `RoaringBitmap`? Is that a third party framework of some kind? Can you provide a link to information about it?

Comment: https://github.com/RoaringBitmap

Comment: You should edit your question to provide that information. Don't make future readers of this thread go on a "scavenger hunt" through the comments to figure out what you are talking about. (I'm using the third part library "RoaringBitmap" (link) which allows me to `<what it does for me>`. I want to be able to export the data from a `RoaringBitmap` and convert it to base64 encoded data so I can ____."

Answer (score 1):

As per Daniel's help [on GitHub](https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/SwiftRoaring/issues/1) it seems I used wrong parameter for the size. The correct syntax is following:

```
let size = rbm.portableSizeInBytes()
var buffer = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: size)
_ =  rbm.portableSerialize(buffer: &buffer)
let uint8Buffer = buffer.map { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
let base64Encoded = Data(uint8Buffer).base64EncodedString()
```